# Using dateFormatter's on swift

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter

```
var dateString = "Sat, 18 Jun 2016 11:00:00 +0900"

var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "E, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"
var dateFromString = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)

dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "ko_KR")
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .FullStyle
var dateFromStringToKorean = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(dateFromString!)
```

This code working in Playground.

but When I build this code in my iPhone it doesn't work.

Could you tell me what's the problem of this code.

Comment: `it doesn't work` What do you mean by that? Is there an error message, what happens?

Comment: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

dateFromString is nil

Comment: and also working in simulator. Just didn't work in iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

Set `locale` property of `dateFormatter` before using it, as below:

```
var dateString = "Sat, 18 Jun 2016 11:00:00 +0900"

var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "E, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "ko_KR")
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .FullStyle

var dateFromString = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)
var dateFromStringToKorean = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(dateFromString!)
```

Comment: It's still didn't work... dateFromString is nil. others works this code. this mean is my xcode or my iphone's problem?